# Unexpected responses to some Magic Values

Tags: opayo

when i set my cardholder to be either NOTENROLLED or TECHNICALDIFFICULTIES the wrong values are returned from Sage Pay V.4.0

As per the documentation, I expected the 3DSecureStatus response to be  NOAUTH and INCOMPLETE respectively but i am getting Status = 3DAuth and 3dSecureStatus = OK for NOTENROLLED and OK,OK for TECHNICALDIFFICULTIES.

All other magic values returned expected results.

Is this to do with my 3D Secure settings in Test sagepay?  I haven't specifically set any rules, just left all as default

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at an older version of the direct guide.

re: `TECHNICALDIFFICULTIES` - the value is (now) actually `TECHDIFFICULTIES`

And the latest version of the guide says that `NOTENROLLED` will "Fallback to 3DSv1" rather than returning a 3DSecureStatus of `NOAUTH` which was what the previous version of the guide said.

The latest version of the guide is [here](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf).

Comment: If anyone finds this looking for the NOTENROLLED magic value, this has been removed from Opayo documentation as of 13/9/2022: https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-direct/change-log

Answer (score 0):

Top man/woman.  that's the answer.  Sage have cunningly changed the document but kept the status of Draft with the same date and version number.  useful.!

I am hoping there haven't been any other changes to the doc.

If anyone from Sage is following this forum it would be good to have a version history in the documentation to stop anyone else having this type of problem.

Thanks for the tip